# C++ Скритие меню в трее при клике где угодно

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, clr

День добрий. Пишу приложение на С++ Clr WinForm .net framework в Visual Studio 2019. Одна из функций которая нужна это меню трея при нажатии на лкм.
Меню и трей я сделал с помощу contextMenuStrip и notifyIcon. Меню работает, но возникла проблема.
Если открить меню в трее оно не закривается при нажатии на рабочий стол как все другие приложения(ShareX как пример).
Прошу подсказать если кто-то знает как это организовать.

```
        // 
                // contextMenuStrip1
                // 
                this->contextMenuStrip1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(1) { this->closeToolStripMenuItem });
                this->contextMenuStrip1->Name = L"contextMenuStrip1";
                this->contextMenuStrip1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(104, 26);
                this->contextMenuStrip1->AutoClose = true;
                // 
                // closeToolStripMenuItem
                // 
                this->closeToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"closeToolStripMenuItem";
                this->closeToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(103, 22);
                this->closeToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"Close";
                this->closeToolStripMenuItem->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MainForm::closeToolStripMenuItem_Click);
    // 
                // notifyIcon1
                // 
                this->notifyIcon1->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^>(resources->GetObject(L"notifyIcon1.Icon")));
                this->notifyIcon1->Text = L"ZoomBot";
                this->notifyIcon1->DoubleClick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MainForm::notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);
                this->notifyIcon1->MouseClick += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler(this, &MainForm::notifyIcon1_MouseClick);

private: System::Void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e) {
    if (e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Right && context_flag == 0)
    {
        contextMenuStrip1->Show(Cursor->Position);
        contextMenuStrip1->Visible = true;
        context_flag = 1;
    }
    else if((e->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Right && context_flag == 1)) {
        contextMenuStrip1->Close();
        context_flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно WinAPI-меню отличается от  contextMenuStrip. Думаю у вас два пути, или пробуйте вывести меню другим способом вывсести меню, например через WinAPI, или... словите событие показа меню, и проверяйте GetCapture, Как только Capture потерян - прячьте меню.

Comment: Обрабатывайте события потери фокуса.

Comment: А вообще, контекстное меню само по себе должно скрываться. Просто назначьте его стандартным способом. | Покажите код, как вы сделали его показ.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Добавил код в вопрос

Comment: Просто назначьте это контекстное меню этому нотифаю в окошке свойств.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо. Заработало. Весде где видил контекстное меню, било сделано через клик а оказивается можно било так сделать.